# Creating two lists from string excluding and including strings between brackets

Tags: python, list, pandas, list-comprehension

Supouse that we have a string like:

```
s = u'apple banana lemmon (hahaha) dog cat whale (hehehe) red blue black'
```

I want to create the following lists:

```
including = ['hahaha', 'hehehe']
excluding = ['apple banana lemmon (', ') dog cat whale (', ') red blue black']
```

First list is direct using regex:

```
including = re.findall('\((.*?)\)',s)
```

But I cannot get something similar for the other list. Could you help me? Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Use the including list to split the string?

Comment: `re.split('|'.join(including), s)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
excluding = re.split('|'.join(including), s)
```

For a simple case where you know the containg information will not contain special characters or regex definitions.

If you are not sure if that will be the case:

```
re.split('|'.join(map(re.escape, including)), s)
```

This will escape the special regex characters that would otherwise cause dysfunction with the re.split function

Comment: It's better to use `map(re.escape, including)` otherwise if you have like `(haha\d+haha)` in the string the regex would interpret `\d+` as one or more digits instead of a literal `\d+`.

Comment: that is true, but I do not think it would apply to a case scenario the askee would work with (i think) since it seems like he is extracting brackets info from real sentences. then again, I could be wrong

Comment: SO Q&A should be helpful to more than just the original asker. So somebody having a similar problem may well need to call `re.escape`.

Comment: Does he have `including` beforehand?

Comment: yes, its the simple regex `including = re.findall('\((.*?)\)',s)`

Answer (score 3):

## With RegEx

```
a = re.findall('\)?[^()]*\(?', s)
excluded = a[::2]
included = a[1::2]
print(included, excluded, sep='\n')

['hahaha', 'hehehe', '']
['apple banana lemmon (', ') dog cat whale (', ') red blue black']
```

### Take care of empty strings

```
a = re.findall('\)?[^()]*\(?', s)
excluded = [*filter(bool, a[::2])]
included = [*filter(bool, a[1::2])]
print(included, excluded, sep='\n')

['hahaha', 'hehehe']
['apple banana lemmon (', ') dog cat whale (', ') red blue black']
```

---

## No RegEx

```
from itertools import cycle

def f(s):
  c = cycle('()')
  a = {'(': 1, ')': 0}
  while s:
    d = next(c)
    i = s.find(d)
    if i > -1:
      j = a[d]
      yield d, s[:i + j]
      s = s[i + j:]
    else:
      yield d, s
      break

included = []
excluded = []

for k, v in f(s):
  if k == '(':
    excluded.append(v)
  else:
    included.append(v)

print(included, excluded, sep='\n')

['hahaha', 'hehehe']
['apple banana lemmon (', ') dog cat whale (', ') red blue black']
```

---

### Same idea without overwriting `s`

```
from itertools import cycle

def f(s):
  c = cycle('()')
  a = {'(': 1, ')': 0}
  j = 0
  while True:
    d = next(c)
    i = s.find(d, j)
    if i > -1:
      k = a[d]
      yield d, s[j:i + k]
      j = i + k
    else:
      yield d, s[j:]
      break

included = []
excluded = []

for k, v in f(s):
  if k == '(':
    excluded.append(v)
  else:
    included.append(v)

print(included, excluded, sep='\n')

['hahaha', 'hehehe']
['apple banana lemmon (', ') dog cat whale (', ') red blue black']
```

Comment: This is a better and more concise answer than mine, should be noted as accepted one instead

Comment: Small clarification if you could: your regex is assuming a known number of cases of brackets, wouldnt it be better to use something like a small parser into two lists?

Answer (score 1):

You may use a positive lookbehind and positive lookahead to split on words between parenthesis:

```
>>> re.split(r'(?<=\().*?(?=\))', s)
['apple banana lemmon (', ') dog cat whale (', ') red blue black']
```